# What is the way to explain these two grammar points?

Tags: grammar

I'm looking for an easy way to explain the grammar in these two sentences

1. I'm eating an apple
2. What I'm eating is an apple

What are the grammatical terms or ways of explaining these two?
I want to explain this grammar point in another language, so I want to know a way to explain the difference between these two.
The only explanation I could come up with is, the 1st one is focusing on the verb and the 2nd one is focusing on the object. What are the grammatical terms for these two concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is Subject - Verb - Object

The subject is "I" the verb is "'m eating" and the object is "apple".

2. is a copula sentence.

The subject is "What I'm eating" (which contains the embedded clause). The copular verb is "is" and the complement is "an apple"

So the first sentence indicates my action and the object that receives that action. It is a sentence about "I/me". The second sentence identifies the thing that I am eating.  It is a sentence about that thing.

The first sentence states that I'm eating.  That same fact may be infered from the second sentence. It is assumed, not stated.

Comment: The second is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)